# Ui Router - nested view not showing up ($viewContentLoaded not fired)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, angular-ui-router, nested-views

views/index.jade:

```
extends layout

block content
  div(ui-view)
```

views/partials/user.jade

```
h1 Route 1
hr
a(ui-sref=".profile") Show Content
div(ui-view)
```

js/appStates.js

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/user");

    $stateProvider
      .state('user', {
        url: '/user',
        templateUrl: 'partials/user'
      })
      .state('user.profile', {
        url: '/profile',
        template: '<h1>My Contacts</h1>'
      })
    ;
  }
]);
```

'My Contacts' Never shows up.
Note the link does seems correct. Not sure what's going on.

I tried the following:

http://tech.endeepak.com/blog/2014/05/03/debugging-angular-ui-router/

and I noticed '$viewContentLoaded' is never called on the nested view, not sure why.
Any cases where it shouldn't be called?

Answer (score 1):

From quick help in IRC channel, I managed to solved it.

the problem is with line 4 in jade file:

```
div(ng-view)
```

From some reason jade by default will render empty attributes with value equal the name.
so the result html was:

```
<div ng-view="ng-view"></view>
```

an easy fix was to set it to empty value in jade

```
div(ng-view="")
```

And now it works.

Thanks again for the people over at the IRC.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gulp specify the document type as html5 so jade knows that nameless tags are valid

coffee script example

```
# Compile jade to html
gulp.task 'jade', ->
  gulp.src paths.jade
  .pipe jade({pretty: true, doctype: 'html')
```